# Dijit: cannot edit all textboxes in the first dialog after showing the second dialog

Tags: dojo, dialog

I set dijitDialogUnderlayWrapper as none display to show the two dialog boxes (both of them contains textboxes) one by one on screen.

The problem is that when I click back on the first dialog, all textboxes on it cannot be edited until I closed the second dialog. However, all textboxes on the second dialog can be edited whenever I click on it.

What I want to do is that when I activate (focus on) one of dialog boxes, all textboxes on that dialog also can be edited. I tried to use"focusUtil.focus" on the first dialog but failure. Anyone have idea? 
Thanks.

Here is the source: jsfiddle.net/Calgis/aL5auzja/

Comment: It is very hard to help you like this.
Can you set up a snippets or a jsFiddle ?

Comment: Thanks Ben. Source is posted on jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/Calgis/aL5auzja/

Answer (score 0):

The `Dialog` on top is the only one able to get `focus`. This is by design.
You can see the dojo code for reference :
https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/Dialog.js#L674-L691

There is no nice way to avoid that with `Dialog`.
However, there is a little hack (note: it may cause other problems).
You have to override the `focus` method of the dialog by an empty one.

In the snippets, the key part is `data-dojo-props="focus:function(){}"`

```js
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dijit/form/TimeTextBox"], function(parser) {
  parser.parse()
});

document.body.className = "tundra"; //only usefull in the snippets
```

```css
.dijitDialogUnderlayWrapper{
  display:none !important
  }
  .nonModal{
   background-color:rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.9);
        }
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css"> 


<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-props="focus:function(){}" data-dojo-id="myFormDialog" title="Dialog1">

    <div class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="Firstname">First Name: </label></td>
                <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" type="text" name="name" id="firstname"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><label for="Lastname">Last Name: </label></td>
                <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" type="text" name="name" id="lastname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="date">Date: </label></td>
                <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" data-dojo-id="myStartDate" onChange="myEndDate.constraints.min = arguments[0];" type="text" name="sdate" id="sdate"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td><label for="desc">Description: </label></td>
                <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" type="text" name="desc" id="desc"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" onClick="return myFormDialog.isValid();">
            OK
        </button>
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" onClick="myFormDialog.hide()">
            Cancel
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-props="focus:function(){}" data-dojo-id="myFormDialog2" title="Dialog2">

    <div class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="name">Name: </label></td>
                <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" type="text" name="name2" id="name2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="date">Date: </label></td>
                <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" data-dojo-id="myStartDate" onChange="myEndDate.constraints.min = arguments[0];" type="text" name="sdate2" id="sdate2"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td><label for="desc">Description: </label></td>
                <td><input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" type="text" name="desc" id="desc2"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" onClick="return myFormDialog2.isValid();">
            OK
        </button>
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" onClick="myFormDialog2.hide()">
            Cancel
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Click button to show dialogs:</p>
<button id="buttonThree" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" onClick="myFormDialog.show();">
    Show Dialog 1
</button>
<button id="buttonThree2" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" onClick="myFormDialog2.show();">
    Show Dialog 2
</button>
```

Comment: If dialog is not the appropriate one, which dijit should be more appropriate? Any sample can be referenced? By the way, Do you know the way to popup the dialog on the left-hand side? Thank you so much.

Comment: You can try the FloatingPane : https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/layout/FloatingPane.html
Dialog will always be centered. Again, the FloatingPane may solve the positioning